# SELENIUM - Getting the followers count from Instagram

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hey Im trying to scrape data from instagram. I am using selinium for that. I am facing a problem when trying to scrape the followers from the profile. My code is as follows:

```
try:
            html = self.__scrape_page()
            page = self.__parse_page(html)
            #followers = page.find_all("meta", attrs={"name": "description"})
            followers = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mount_0_0_mC > div > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div > div > div.x78zum5.xdt5ytf.x10cihs4.x1t2pt76.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div.x9f619.xnz67gz.x78zum5.x168nmei.x13lgxp2.x5pf9jr.xo71vjh.x1uhb9sk.x1plvlek.xryxfnj.x1c4vz4f.x2lah0s.x1q0g3np.xqjyukv.x1qjc9v5.x1oa3qoh.x1qughib > div.x1gryazu.xh8yej3.x10o80wk.x14k21rp.x17snn68.x6osk4m.x1porb0y > div:nth-child(2) > section > main > div > header > section > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span > span")
            return followers
        
        #     followers_count = (followers[0]["content"].split(",")[0].split(" ")[0])
        #     return {
        #         "data": followers_count,
        #         "message": f"Followers found for user {self.username}",
        #     }
        except Exception as e:
            message = f"{self.username} not found!"
            return {"data": None, "message": message}
```

It is only giving me `[]` as the result. I tried using XPATH as well but in the end `[]` is all Im getting.